# Error instantiating Controller class C#

Tags: c#, controller

When trying to create an instance of my Controller class I keep getting the error - system.web.mvc.controller is defined in assembly not referenced.

Code:

```
public void Setup()
{
    ProcessController _processController = new ProcessController();
}
```

Comment: All information written in exception - you should to add reference to system.web.mvc

Comment: That type should be defined in `System.Web.Mvc`, no?  Add a reference to that assembly.

Comment: Thanks @David that fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David was right, I needed to reference `System.Web.Mvc`.